# Could the information of flight crew or maintenance personnel be provided to passengers?

Tags: regulations

Many passengers experience insecure or anxious feelings during flight. If they were provided aircraft performance info, flight crew or maintenance personnel's info(say personnels have many years of experience), which indicates flight is checked and safe, they may not be worried during flight.
I wonder if there's any regulation or law regarding to this issue. Does anybody happen to know it?
Thanks!

Comment: ...then what would happen to anxious passengers if they were told the crew was relatively young and inexperienced?

Comment: The fact that we're going flying, means that I as the captain, along with any number of others in Dispatch, Maintenance, Operations, and other places, all agree that everything is up to standards & we can operate the flight safely.  If that wasn't the case, we wouldn't be pushing back from the gate.  So no, you aren't going to get a massive data dump that includes the coffee maker in the aft galley being replaced last week and 1001 other irrelevant details.

Comment: "One compass, and one radio altimeter are broken. An engine is due for maintenance, and the tires will need to be changed after the next landing. Our captain is going through a divorce, the purser is a psychopath, and this plane is 25 years old. According to the regulations, everything is up to standards & we can operate the flight safely. Enjoy your flight and don't worry!"     ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If they were provided aircraft performance info, flight crew or maintenance personnel's info(say personnel have many years of experience), which indicates flight is checked and safe, they may not be worried during flight.

Not a bunch of log and personnel files, but various certificates guarantee a flight is "checked and safe". The most important ones I can currently think of are the [air operator's certificate](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Air_Operator_Certificate_(AOC)) (given to an airline) and the [airworthiness certificate](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Certificate_of_Airworthiness) (given to an aircraft).

To address the regulatory aspects of your question:

- personnel info will be subject to privacy regulations and therefore would not be shared with passengers;
- maintenance logs are often company confidential, and are therefore not shared.

Comment: The FAA makes safety-related maintenance issues [public information](https://av-info.faa.gov/sdrx/).

Answer (score 3):

Averaging roughly 300 commercial flights per year, I have yet to meet someone anxious or insecure due to missing aircraft performance info or flight crew info, simply because they would still not be able to gauge relative safety to a self-comforting level. The average person with flight anxiety is essentially irrationally afraid of dying due to little knowledge of publicly available transportation safety statistics and math. Have a look at http://planecrashinfo.com/cause.htm.

While interesting for some, offering information on aircraft performance info, flight crew or maintenance personnel's info - apart from the questionable legal standpoint - with the implicitly needed hinting towards safety would be lying, as there is no quantifiable correlation between such information and safety. I happily stand corrected.

Comment: You _average_ 300 flights per year? Realizing that getting from A to B often means stopping in C & D along the way and requires 3 flights, that's still a _lot_ of days in the air! Yikes!

Comment: @FreeMan: In the 21hrs between my reply and your comment, I boarded 4 flights in Europe. Yes, it's a lot of days (about 900-1000hrs) in the air. This amount of flying has obviously earned me the highest status with the largest alliances, so I don't have to endure traditional hassle getting from A to B.